# Trimmed ResourceId from Get-AzResource | Where-Object { } - Azure

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to update tags on a resources array generated using a where-object filter, used to pick only non tagged resources. Update-AzTag fails due to a null ResourceId, however if I filter resources based on name the command works fine. I've noticed that a lot of times the ResourceId is just trimmed, missing the last 10 chars.

```
$resources = Get-AzResource | Where-Object {$_.Tags -eq $null}
$tags = @{"owner"="pmantz"; "product"="product"}
foreach ($resource in $resources) {
     Update-AzTag -ResourceId $resource.Id -Tag $tags -Operation Merge
}
```

Using
`$resources = Get-AzResource | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "name"}` works fine

any idea what might be causing this?

it seems the issue is with the resourceid values, for some reason even using them simply like this fails for an existing resource,

```
Update-AzTag -ResourceId "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/Azure-Splunk-Monitor-AppStg/providers/microsoft.insights/alertrules/xms2_origDTUAlertOver80Percent" -Tag $tags -Operation Merge
Update-AzTag: {"code":"TargetResourceNotFound","message":"The target resource id '/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/xm-staging1-westus-uemy/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/xmsdb-xm-staging1-westus-uemy/datab
ases/xms2_orig' was not found."}
```

at the same time Get-AzResource works just fine

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceId /subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/Azure-Splunk-Monitor-AppStg/providers/microsoft.insights/alertrules/xms2_origDTUAlertOver80Percent

Name              : xms2_origDTUAlertOver80Percent
ResourceGroupName : Azure-Splunk-Monitor-AppStg
ResourceType      : Microsoft.Insights/alertRules
Location          : westus
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/Azure-Splunk-Monitor-AppStg/prov
                    iders/microsoft.insights/alertrules/xms2_origDTUAlertOver80Percent
Tags              :
                    Name
                                                                                                           Value
                    ===================================================================================================
                    =====================================================================================  ========
                    hidden-link:/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/xm-staging1-westus-u
                    emy/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/xmsdb-xm-staging1-westus-uemy/databases/xms2_orig  Resource
```

update

apparently the alert rules in question were associated with deleted resources that prevented tagging of the alert rules themselves.

Comment: Does `$resource | Update-AzTag -Tag $tags -Operation Merge` work? (according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/update-aztag?view=azps-4.7.0) the `ResourceId` parameter has position 0 and accepts pipeline input)

Answer (score 0):

because its `$resource.resourceId`

Comment: that's not it. id is an alias for ResourceId actually, I have been using this with a simple et-AzResource just fine. the Where-object is what breaks this but I don't know why

Comment: you are right about the alias, however where-object doesnt break anything, it works fine for me

Comment: that's strange as I have tested on my PC, Azure Vm and Azure automation and it doesn't work anywhere.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27297775).